# How to get multiple records one record using query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to be able to query from this data:

```
parking_place | number_of_month  | from_date | end_date  | monthly_unit_price
A             | 3                | 2018-01   | 2018-03   | 3000000
```

Desire to show results:

```
parking_place | month   | monthly_unit_price
A             | 2018-01 | 3000000
A             | 2018-02 | 3000000
A             | 2018-03 | 3000000
```

please suggest me how to query?

Answer (score 0):

You may join using a calendar table:

```
SELECT
    t.parking_place,
    t.month,
    t.monthly_unit_price
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-01' AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-03'
) months
INNER JOIN yourTable t
    ON months.month BETWEEN t.from_date AND t.end_date
ORDER BY
    months.month;
```

Note that it would be better to store actual valid date literals to represent each month.  For example, instead of storing the text `'2018-01'`, you could store `2018-01-01` as a date literal.